# OpenVPN subject name verification (verify-x509-name) with Subject Alternative Name (SAN)

Tags: openvpn, certificate, ssl-certificate

I run an OpenVPN gateway which is reachable unter two different host names (one from outside, one internally). For this reason I have created a certificate with a Subject Alternative Name field, which has both host names. The subject (DN) of the certificate has the internal host name.

When I use that certificate for HTTPS, everything works as expected—the certificate is accepted as valid for either host name.

With OpenVPN’s `verify-x509-name` option, however, the server certificate will be rejected unless I specify the internal name (as in the DN).

Is there a way to get OpenVPN’s subject name verification to work in the same manner as a web browser, i.e. accepting any matching subject name?

Answer (score 1):

## Short Answer

*DNS Subject Alternative Names*, which would be most useful in client mode to verify the names in the server certificate, just like browsers do, are (as of version 2.5) unfortunately *not supported*.

## Long Answer

As of version 2.5, OpenVPN has following three options for verifying names contained in remote X.509 certificates.:

- Verifying the whole X.509 Subject field against a given `$subject` with `--verify-x509-name $subject subject`
- Verifying the value of a single RDN component of the subject against a given `$name` with `--verify-x509-name $name name` and `--x509-username-field $fieldname`
- Verifying an `email` Subject Alternative Name or `email` Issuer Alternative Name with `--verify-x509-name $name name` and `--x509-username-field ext:subjectAltName` or `--x509-username-field ext:issuerAltName`.

The default `--x509-username-field` is the common name `CN`.

Verifying Issuer Alternative Name is rather questionable, because this field describes the CA certificate that signed the remote certificate.

Instead of an exact match of the full RDN component or email alternative name only a prefix may be matched, if `--verify-x509-name $name name-prefix` is specified instead of `--verify-x509-name $name name`.

All options are available both in server mode to verify names in the remote client certificates and client mode to verify names in the remote server certificates. The options work exactly the same in both modes. The fact, that only `email` alternative names are supported and that the option is called `--x509-username-field` suggests however, that this option was mainly designed for verifying client certificates on the server side.

*DNS Subject Alternative Names*, which would be most useful in client mode to verify the names in the server certificate, just like browsers do, are (as of version 2.5) unfortunately *not supported*.

Also worth noting is the fact, that alternative name fields are (as of version 2.5) only supported with [OpenVPN's OpenSSL backend](https://github.com/OpenVPN/openvpn/blob/release/2.5/src/openvpn/ssl_verify_openssl.c#L127) and [not with the mbedTLS](https://github.com/OpenVPN/openvpn/blob/release/2.5/src/openvpn/ssl_verify_mbedtls.c#L110).